# Search for a char in the key of a Map

Tags: scala

I would like to make this method high-order function.

The idea is Sending a Map of key value and search for a char "." Dot if exists in key.

```
  def findChar(mymap: Map[String, Any]): Boolean = {
    val pattern = "^.*\\..*$".r
    mymap.keys.foreach {
      case pattern() => return true
      case _ => None
    }
    return false
  }
```

> i am calling this function
>
> ```
> if (findChar(attributes)) {
>             DO something
>
>  } else {
>            DO something else }
> ```

how can i use the "exsits" method here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it, if you explicitly need `exists`:

```
map.keys.exists(_.contains("."))
```